# android app : layout xml files

Tags: android

can anyone tell me what is the main difference between main.xml and Activity_main.xml.

I am writing a sample pgm for a simple client server communication.In the tutorial that am following it says to add the following code in main.xml which the author says is inside layout folder. but in my package explorer main.xml is shown inside the menu folder and in my layout folder, i have only activity_main and fragment_main. this is the code that has been posted in the website.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android=”http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android”


  android:orientation=”vertical”


  android:layout_width=”fill_parent”

  android:layout_height=”fill_parent”>

  <ListView android:id=”@+id/list”

  android:layout_width=”fill_parent”

  android:layout_height=”0dip”

  android:layout_weight=”1″

  android:transcriptMode=”alwaysScroll”

  android:cacheColorHint=”#00000000″

  android:listSelector=”@android:color/transparent”/>

  <LinearLayout android:id=”@+id/footer”

  android:layout_width=”fill_parent”

  android:layout_height=”wrap_content”

  android:orientation=”horizontal”

  android:gravity=”bottom”>

 <EditText android:inputType=”textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions”

     android:layout_width=”0dp”

     android:layout_height=”40dp”

     android:id=”@+id/editText”

     android:layout_weight=”1″/>

     <Button android:layout_width=”wrap_content”

      android:layout_height=”wrap_content”

      android:id=”@+id/send_button”

      android:layout_gravity=”center_vertical”

      android:text=”send” />

      </LinearLayout>

      </LinearLayout>
```

my question is where exactly am i supposed to use this code? in main.xml in menu             folder or activity_main.xml? plz help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Put the code in the activity_main.xml file.**

activity_main.xml and main.xml described in your tutorial are referring the same thing (a layout file). You can find it under 'res/layout' in the package explorer in ADT.

(Do not put the layout code in the .xml file in the menu folder)

You could actually name the .xml file anything you want as long as it is properly declared in your Java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);//<-------your xml file is declared here
```

I believe it is just the newer version of ADT that names the file activity_main.xml by default.

Whatever your tutorial is saying in regards to main.xml use your activity_main.xml instead.

alternatively from within ADT navigate to 'res/layout' and right click on the activity_main.xml select refactor->rename and rename the file to main.xml so everything matches your tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the code in **layout/activity_main.xml**. The tutorial main.xml corresponds to your activity_main.xml. This is the xml that is inflated in your Launcher activity (normally using setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) api in onCreate() function). This xml name can be anything. While creating the application, you get the option to give name to this xml. The default name is activity_xml.

The main.xm which is inside menu folder is used for sub menus in your applicaion. If you click the menu button inside your application, sub menu will come up. The layout of this sub menus is controlled by main.xml in menu folder.

Answer (score 0):

> where exactly am i supposed to use this code

This code would go inside `activity_main.xml` because it is a `layout` file.

### **menus**

If it was a menu it would look a lot different such as having menu items instead of `View`s. And it would start and end with the `<menu> </menu>` tags. A menu file can be inflated to be used with your menu buttons whether that be a hard menu button, from the `ActionBar`, or inflated to be used somewhere else.

[Menus](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)

### **layouts**

`layouts` will contain your `View`s such as `ViewGroups` (`LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, etc..) and child `View`s like `TextView`s, `Button`s, etc... The `layout` files can be named whatever you like (assuming they follow the naming conventions for `layout` file names). Then you use that name in your `Activity` to set the `layout` using `setContentView(R.layout.some_layout_name)`

[Layouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is layout code; it should go into layout/activity_main.xml. The menu/main.xml file describes a menu named 'main'.